# Server supporting multiple clients with listen maybe?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, client

I was writing a simple server, just for fun and I realized that the third step meaning calling the  `listen(...)` function takes two arguments. The second one being the `backlog`. While I don't fully understand the meaning of this argument but I think it queues up the clients. So assuming I'm right I was wondering how the server moves up the queue or do I actually've to implement that?

I did find many examples online about it but they mostly contain code. I would like a more theoretical explanation. 
Thanks!

Comment: For more theoretical explanation u can read section 4.5 from Unix network programming by stevens...its a nice explanation for backlog. Read here [link](http://82.157.70.109/mirrorbooks/unixnetworkprogramming/0131411551_ch04lev1sec5.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right - backlog is the supposed queue of possible connections (AFAIK it is ignored on Linux)

After you create a listening socket you call accept() on it and assuming your socket is blocking - the accept call shall not return until it pull the first client request off the queue.

So you can do something like

```
listen();
while(int in_socket=accept())
{
    if(in_socket>0)
    // process each client in order they are received
}
```